# Coefficient problem using multinomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

i want to solve this: consider $(x+y+z)^n$, let $n=1000$ the coefficient of $x^{320}y^{410}z^{270}$ can
be written as
$\binom{a}{b} \cdot \binom{c}{d}$.

find $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$

my attempt is using the multinomial theorem, so I get that the coefficient of $x^{320}y^{410}z^{270}$

$\frac{1000!}{320! \cdot 410! \cdot 270!}=\binom{a}{b} \cdot \binom{c}{d}=\frac{a! \cdot b!}{b!\cdot (a-b)!\cdot d! \cdot (c-d)!}$

But from here i cannot find some relation for $a,b,c$ and $d$.

Comment: You may have a typo: perhaps you intended $\binom{a}{b} \cdot \binom{c}{d}=\frac{a! \cdot c!}{b!\cdot (a-b)!\cdot d! \cdot (c-d)!}$

Comment: There is more than one answer, but perhaps try $c=a-b$

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea. As [@Henry](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6460/henry)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4481250/coefficient-problem-using-multinomial-theorem/4481254#comment9396270_4481250) indicates, there's more than one answer. From what you started, here's how to get one of those answers:

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{1000!}{320! \cdot 410! \cdot 270!} & = \left(\frac{1000!}{320! \cdot 410! \cdot 270!}\right)\left(\frac{730!}{730!}\right) \\
& = \left(\frac{1000!}{270!\cdot 730!}\right)\left(\frac{730!}{320!\cdot 410!}\right) \\
& = \binom{1000}{270} \cdot \binom{730}{320}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Start from your left-hand side and find a representation with binomial coefficients by properly expanding numerator and denominator. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{1000!}{320! \cdot 410! \cdot 270!}=\frac{1000!}{320!(1000-320)!}\,\frac{(1000-320)!}{410!\cdot 270!}
\color{blue}{=\binom{1000}{320}\binom{680}{410}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Well, ${1000\choose 320,410,270} = {1000\choose 320}\cdot {{1000-320}\choose 420}\cdot {{1000-320-410}\choose 270}$, where the last coefficient is $1$.